# bug ONLY in chrome when I sort my <tr> and after click to Refresh or click to sortable Colum all my <tr> lose their width

Tags: google-chrome, jqgrid

It only bug on chrome (I have last version)

When you reorganise tr on table and when you click to refresh icon or when you click to column to sort it ! all tr lose their width !

You can see it on the demonstration page from trirand (official webpage of jqgrid)

1. http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html
2. Click to : New in version 3.6
3. Click to : Sortable Rows

And try to sort any tr just one time or many time and after click to REFRESH icon you will see a strange result ... only on chrome (ff and ie are OK)